# Need to expand row# 3 and column# 0 but do not want row #1 and column# to expand

Tags: python, tkinter, grid-layout

I am using grid geometry and my need is to expand only the canvas on maximizing of the window. The canvas is on a frame which is at row#3 and column#0.
When I do 
master.grid_rowconfigure(3,weight=1)
self.canvasFrame.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
then the canvas gets expaned on the row but I also need to expand it on the column.
so I did
master.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
self.canvasFrame.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

but it also expanded the column#0 of row#1. I do not want that.

Here is my code.

Is it possible to achieve using grid geometry manager?

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

class MainUI:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master

        # row 1
        ttk.Label(self.master, text="Customer").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, pady = 5, padx = 15)
        ttk.Label(self.master, text="Items").grid(row=0,column=1, sticky=W, pady = 5, padx = 15)
        ttk.Label(self.master, text="Price").grid(row=0,column=2, sticky=W, pady = 5, padx = 15)
        ttk.Label(self.master, text="Cost").grid(row=0,column=3, sticky=W, pady = 5, padx = 15)

        # row 2
        self.customerCombo = ttk.Combobox( self.master, 
                                            values=[])
        self.customerCombo.grid(row=1,column=0, sticky=W, pady = 5, padx = 15)

        self.jobCombo = ttk.Combobox( self.master, 
                                            values=[])
        self.jobCombo.grid(row=1,column=1, sticky=W, pady = 5, padx = 15)

        self.estLaborEntry = ttk.Entry(self.master).grid(row=1,column=2, sticky=W, pady = 5, padx = 15)
        self.estMaterialEntry = ttk.Entry(self.master).grid(row=1,column=3, sticky=W, pady = 5, padx = 15)

        # row 3
        self.addRowButton = ttk.Button(self.master, command=self.show, text="Add Row").grid(row=2, column = 2, sticky=W, pady = 5, padx = 15)
        self.addRowButton = ttk.Button(self.master, command=self.show, text="Add Col").grid(row=2, column = 3, sticky=W, pady = 5, padx = 15)

        #row 4
        self.canvasFrame = Frame(master)


        self.canvasFrame.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=W+E+N+S, pady=5, padx=15)
        master.grid_rowconfigure(3,weight=1)
        master.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        xscrollbar = Scrollbar(self.canvasFrame, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        xscrollbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E+W)

        yscrollbar = Scrollbar(self.canvasFrame)
        yscrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)

        canvas = Canvas(self.canvasFrame, bd=0, 
                        scrollregion=(0, 0, 1000, 1000),
                        xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set,
                        yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)
        canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)
        self.canvasFrame.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.canvasFrame.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
    def show(self):
        messagebox.showinfo("title", "message")
def on_closing():
    root.destroy()
#     from tkinter import messagebox
#     if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you want to quit?"):
#         root.destroy()


root = Tk()   
mainui = MainUI(root)
root.title("Test")
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: maybe you can provide a picture as your expected output?

Comment: If you want the four columns to be evenly distributed horizontally, you should set `weight=1` on the four columns, not just column#0.  Also should the `columnspan` be set to 4 for `self.canvasFrame`?

Comment: Thanks guys for your comments, I got it working.